# Laravel 4 - User authentication remember me

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could show me how to implement the remember me function in Laravel 4

The docs say to use the following

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
```

But that means the remember me will always be set to true ... What if i had a checkbox to allow the user to toggle if they want it or not.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), Input::has('remember_me')))
```

Comment: Would that mean the checkbox 'value' should be set to true?

Comment: True or 1, just set it to a value so that the value is sent when they check the box and submit the form.